# Rails response depending on http request format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, http, devise

I want to build a website that respond both to normal browser request, and mobile request using JSON from an Android app.
I use devise for authentication. Web users will login normally, but for mobile use, I want them to send login/password only once, and then work with the authentication token.
To do that, I overrided the devise session controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
respond_to :html, :json

def create
  resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)

  obj1 = MyModel.find(21)
  obj2 = MyModel.find(22)

  respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
      render :json => obj1
      end
      format.json do
      render :json => obj2
      end
  end
end
def destroy
    super
end 
end
```

This is actually a dummy code, just to know which case gets executed in the respond_to. 
If a create a post request, passing login details, like this:

```
curl -v -X POST -d '{"user" : { "email" : "myemail@gmail.com", "password" : "123456"}}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

The response is the JSON representation of obj1. In other words, in the respond_to it always get executed the format.html entry.
What is wrong with this code? Why I get that response if I specify in the header that this is a JSON formatted request?

Comment: I made it work, adding: -H "Accept:application/json" One day trying to fix this, and I figure it out 10 minutes after posting to stackoverflow. Sorry, I hope at least it helps somebody.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work adding: -H "Accept:application/json"